# Visual Studio - Prevent Creation of <Compile> and <None> tags when moving files in CSPROJ

Tags: visual-studio, csproj

In my CSPROJ I have a subfolder ›None‹. It is setup like this:

```xml
<ItemGroup Label="None">
  <Compile Remove="None/**/*.cs" />
  <None Include="None/**/*.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

In there I have CS files, that I don't want to compile.

No, I want to move a file (lets say ‌›CompileIt.cs‹ from ›None‹ back to the project, because now I want to compile it again.

If I move it outside of Visual Studio (like directly in the explorer or via PowerShell) it does exactly what I want, the file is now in a different folder inside the project and the Build-Action changes from ›None‹ to ›C# Compiler‹.

But if I move the file in Visual Studio, something different happens. Visual Studio changes the CSPROJ file like this:

```xml
<ItemGroup Label="None">
  <Compile Remove="None/**/*.cs" />
  <None Include="None/**/*.cs" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="CompileIt.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Now I have to either delete the ItemGroup from the CSPROJ again or change the "Build Action" in the Solution Explorer`s Properties page of the file.

Of course I know, this is usually exactly what you would expect, because normally a build action shouldn't change if you only move the file.

But anyway, is there a way to let Visual Studio know to not change CPSROJ file if I move a file inside it?

Or alternatively, is there a way to mark a subfolder in Visual Studio so that Visual Studios knows it should ignore all files in it?

PS: Oh, I forgot to say this, it is a Core-Style CSPROJ file, that means, all CS files are included automatically.

Comment: BTW If someone is able to come up with a better title, I would gladly change it. I had a problem to really grasp the actual problem with this title.

Comment: I am having this same problem but when I add CSS files in a Razor Pages project where I defined `<PageCssFiles Include="Pages\**\*.css" />`. I have to keep editing the project file to remove the `<None Remove="*.css" />` tags that Visual Studio adds whenever a new CSS file is added to the project. Did you ever find a solution?